# Calculating 2 hourly average of data

Tags: r, datetime

I have flow data for a year. I want to get the 2 hourly averages of the data and make a timeseries that records the average flow for the two hours along with the timestamp.

The data look like this:

```
2005-01-01 00:00:00  18
2005-01-01 00:15:00  18
2005-01-01 00:30:00  18
2005-01-01 00:45:00  18
2005-01-01 01:00:00  18
2005-01-01 01:15:00  18
2005-01-01 01:30:00  18
2005-01-01 01:45:00  19
```

So at the end I would like something that looks like:

```
2005-01-01 00:00:00 18.125
```

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
for (i in seq(1,length(streamflow),8)){
  streamflow2hr[i] <- mean(streamflow[i:i+7])
}
valid2hr <- complete.cases(streamflow2hr)
validIndex <- which(valid2hr,arr.ind = TRUE)
streamflow2hrvalid <- streamflow2hr[validIndex]
streamflow2hrvalidTime <- streamflowDateTime[validIndex]
data2hr <- data.frame(streamflow2hrvalidTime,streamflow2hrvalid)
names(data2hr) <- c("DateTime","Flow")
```

But since I'm using relative positions it isn't consistent with the 2 hourly timestamp!

Comment: Your desired output is unclear.

Comment: do you always have a 15-minute interval?

Comment: Using `cut.POSIXct` would make this very easy to build an aggregation index for either `aggregate` or `tapply`. I'm pretty sure you could find pretty much an exact duplicate if you did a bit of searching with those as search terms. It would be more courteous if in the future you could post the output from `dput` from that object. As it stands it could be one of several different classes whose print outputs are all identical.

Comment: I always have a 15 minute interval but I want to take the average value of the flow on a 2 hour basis. For e.g. the input data is in 15 minute intervals, so the first output would be the first time stamp, i.e. 2005-01-01 00:00:00 and the average flow from the first 8 timestamps flow readings. The next output would be 2005-01-01 00:02:00 and the average flow for the next 8 time stamps flow readings, and so on and so forth! Class for the dates is "POSIXct" "POSIXt" and class for the flow is "numeric"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust this code for your needs:

```
# Generate a sample dataset
set.seed(1)
z <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-31 13:00:00") + 900*0:23
d <- data.frame(t=z,v=sample(length(z)))

d$cut <- cut(d$t,breaks="2 hours")
aggregate(v~cut,d,mean)
#                  cut      v
#1 2015-01-31 13:00:00 12.875
#2 2015-01-31 15:00:00 12.125
#3 2015-01-31 17:00:00 12.500
```

This solution doesn't rely on 15-minute intervals between timestamps. Instead, it divides the time range into 2-hour intervals and uses them to calculate per-interval means.